# proper use of Laravel's paginate method?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

When I use the `paginate` method with the following statement:

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->first();
$images = $user->images->paginate(3);
```

I get the following error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not
>   exist

However when I call it with the following statement:

```
$images = Image::where('user_id', $user->id)->paginate(3);
```

It works accordingly... I'm fairly new to Laravel, so forgive my ignorance, but what is the cause of the difference in results? Don't both statement return collections?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Use `dd($images)` and see the difference.

Comment: `$images = $user->images()->paginate(3);`

Comment: @TruongDang jeez. chronicles of a Django dev migrating to Laravel. I feel like a bafoon! that did the trick.

Comment: you can apply paginate on array if need code for that then plz let me know @John Durand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paginate` is a method of the query builder not the collection. If you want to paginate the collection you need to do manual pagination:

```
$imagesPage = new LengthAwarePaginator($user->images->forPage($page,3), $user->images->count(), 3, $page); //Where $page is the current page number
```

Alternatively you can paginate the query builder:

```
$images = $user->images()->paginate(3);
```

Note that if you use the 2nd approach you don't need to eager load the images.