# use eloquent (or similar) on a json file

Tags: php, json, laravel

I wanna use **laravel eloquent** to filter json array
Is there a way to convert **json array to object** that eloquent could be work on it?

actually I want to use **paginate** and **group by**
piece of my json file:

```json
[{
        "Fact_Num": "1210",
        "Fact_Date": "1399\/01\/12",
        "Fact_Ghabel_Pardakht": 625000,
        "Fact_Kala_ID": "151049",
        "Fact_Tedad": 1,
        "Fact_Price_Joze": 130000,
        "Fact_Price_Kol": 130000
    },
    {
        "Fact_Num": "1210",
        "Fact_Date": "1399\/01\/12",
        "Fact_Ghabel_Pardakht": 625000,
        "Fact_Kala_ID": "6260074000144",
        "Fact_Tedad": 3,
        "Fact_Price_Joze": 65000,
        "Fact_Price_Kol": 195000
    },
    {
        "Fact_Num": "1210",
        "Fact_Date": "1399\/01\/12",
        "Fact_Ghabel_Pardakht": 625000,
        "Fact_Kala_ID": "6260098401149",
        "Fact_Tedad": 1,
        "Fact_Price_Joze": 15000,
        "Fact_Price_Kol": 15000
    },
    {
        "Fact_Num": "1210",
        "Fact_Date": "1399\/01\/12",
        "Fact_Ghabel_Pardakht": 625000,
        "Fact_Kala_ID": "111042",
        "Fact_Tedad": 0.1,
        "Fact_Price_Joze": 1000000,
        "Fact_Price_Kol": 100000
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... from where your getting this data from database ?

Comment: why would you need to use eloquent?  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator

Comment: Eloquent is an ORM, so it is not the appropriate tool for this task. I suggest you look into [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) and use those methods to create a LengthAwarePaginator (I've written [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50226837/487813) on a basic use case at some point)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this package: https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi

It makes eloquent work on arrays.

However, if you only want to group and paginate, you can group with laravels collections (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) and use the laravel paginator to paginate (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator).